# Unable to get Geometry after draw polygon in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

draw.on('drawend', function (e) {

console.log('geom: '+e.feature.getGeometry());

map.removeInteraction(draw);
});

// I want to get the geometry after draw end
// I am new in webGis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the geometry outside the event or after removing the interaction you will need to save it

```
let geometry;

draw.on('drawend', function (e) {
  geometry = e.feature.getGeometry().clone();
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
});
```